# PHP Regex for a specific numeric value inside a comma-delimited integer number string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to get the integer on the left and right for an input from the `$str` variable using REGEX. But I keep getting the commas back along with the integer. I only want integers not the commas. I have also tried replacing the wildcard `.` with `\d` but still no resolution.

```
$str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";

function pagination()
{
    global $str;
    // Using number 4 as an input from the string
    preg_match('/(.{2})(4)(.{2})/', $str, $matches);
    echo $matches[0]."\n".$matches[1]."\n".$matches[1]."\n".$matches[1]."\n";     
}

pagination();
```

Comment: Please write down your expected output.

Comment: And dont use global to get variables into function context. `function pagination($str){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for Regex Non Capture Group

Here's what I did:

```
$regStr = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
$regex = "/(\d)(?:,)(4)(?:,)(\d)/";

preg_match($regex, $regStr, $results);
print_r($results);
```

Gives me the results:

```
Array ( [0] => 3,4,5 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You don't need the non-capture groups, just don't capture the `,`s at all.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a CSV parser?

```
$str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
$line = str_getcsv($str);
$target = 4;
foreach($line as $key => $value) {
if($value == $target) {
   echo $line[($key-1)] . '<--low high-->' . $line[($key+1)];
}
}
```

Output:

```
3<--low high-->5
```

or a regex could be

```
$str = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
preg_match('/(\d+),4,(\d+)/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1]."<--low high->".$matches[2];
```

Output:

```
3<--low high->5
```

The only flaw with these approaches is if the number is the start or end of range. Would that ever be the case?

Answer (score -1):

Given your function name I am going to assume you need this for pagination.

The following solution might be easier:

```
$str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
$str_parts = explode(',', $str);

// reset and end return the first and last element of an array respectively
$start = reset($str_parts);
$end = end($str_parts);
```

This prevents your regex from having to deal with your numbers getting into the double digits.

Comment: OP might need the digits on either side of a specified digit.  Like in their example, 4.  So return 3 and 5.  Not sure though...